# Trigger event inside another event

Tags: jquery

I have been working on a small customization of jPlayer. 
I defined event A, and event B. Both events are triggered separately. However, I am having a problem triggering event A from inside event B.
Event-A:

```
$("jquery_jplayer_1").bind($.jPlayer.event.timeupdate,function(event,param1)
...
)}
```

Event-B:

```
$(".jp-waveform-container").click(function(e))
...
$("jquery_jplayer_1").trigger($.jPlayer.event.timeupdate,[randomVar]);
...
)}
```

Comment: Thanks for the formatting Christian!

Answer (score 0):

Add `$(".jp-waveform-container").trigger('click');` inside your first function (assuming `.jp-waveform-container` is unique). Or make the function in event B a named function and just call it from event A?

Comment: Sorry for the mix up Robin, I am trying to call A from inside B! I cannot make event A a named function, because I need the actual event to access some parameters like:    event.jPlayer.status.duration.